# Theres a woman on the site!

Tags: discussion

[Why do Jehovah's Witnesses have a problem with my relationship with one of their members?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/23366/save-my-relationship)

this is a good question, why/do Jehovah's witnesses need their spouses to convert? Can't someone just fix this question if for no other reason than Christian Chivalry\Charity?

I mean seriously guys, first lady not named Monica to ask a question and we can't even suggest a way to fix the question for her!

Comment: I appreciate the sentiment but take a look at the title: *save my relationship* - on the surface it is asking for pastoral advice. Buried in the text is *my question is do this JW congregation see other Christians as unbelievers?* I think that *this* is an excellent question - if you edit it down to that I will support you in re-opening it.

Comment: not even *close* to the first lady on this site. We've had several, perhaps not as visible, but there have been a number I'm aware of. While the demographics are heavily skewed male, it's not as heavy as one might think.

Comment: If you think its fixable knock yourself out (or better yet ask an appropriate replacement question) but the current iteration is clearly off topic.

Comment: There was one question asked on the Christianity.SE by a Russian Orthodox woman about the incidence of planning weddings close to the bride's menstrual period.

Answer (score 6):

Peter, I am highly sympathetic to the desire to have more women on the site - and, as ashamed as I am to admit it, I go further out of my way for the ladies than I do the men.

That said, the question was 100% a "what should I do" question - not an academic "What is the reasoning behind."  Pastoral Advice is off topic.  I hate it, but that's the way it needs to be.

Prayer is the only answer here.  Get thee to the Prayer Room!

Comment: There I edited it.  She said she was coping with the situation, so I figure leave it at that.  I'm guessing she just wants to know _why_ and that, someone should be able to answer (I think someone owes her an answer!)